# My Excel sheet adds 5 cells and displays them in another cell. I want to see the running total instead of waiting for all 5 cells to be filled

Tags: excel, sum, excel-formula

I believe this should be a pretty simple solution but I really don't know how to go about it..

I have the following formula in cell C20  =SUM(I13:I17)   This is my total wages for that week.  Cells I13-I17 are for Monday - Friday and what I got paid that day.

I would like it to display a running total instead of waiting for all 5 cells to have a number in them. Currently it won't show anything in C20 unless all cells have something. I can't alter anything with the I13-I17 as they are filled by another formula.

I want to be able to see what I've currently earned that week instead of waiting until Friday when all 5 cells have then been filled.

I hope I've explained my self well enough on this. It seems like it would be a very simple thing but I can't figure it out.

Thanks for any help,
Kyle..

Comment: What dos it give you if not all numbers are filled in?  By default the `SUM` function is supposed to ignore blanks and text..

Comment: The I columns aren't blank, they say #VALUE! due to the formula the fills them in.   I have a formula that auto fills the columns depending on the hours worked and what position I select from a drop down menu..

Comment: try `=SUMIF(I13:I17,">0")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this instead

```
=If(I13<>"",If(I14<>"",IF(I15<>"",IF(I16<>"",If(I17<>"",SUM(I13:I17),SUM(I13:I16)),SUM(I13:I15)),SUM(I13:I14)),I13),"0")
```

Comment: I just gave that a shot and it still wants something in all the cells, or zeros, which I can't do because of the formula.. 

I have a formula that auto fills the I columns depending on hours worked and what position I'm working that day. All the I columns by default say   #VALUE!  in them until I select my job that day from a drop down and then input my hours worked...